# Urllib Request only working for one user

Tags: python, http, web, urllib2

im writing a web bot and ive ran into a problem

basically the bot logs in buys and sells shares in a game it works when i put in my username and pass but when i put in a differnt one i get an error saying ive been directed from the wrong page even though i used a Referer header

Here is my Login code:

```
def Login(self):
        while True:
            self.cookieJar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
            self.opener = urllib2.build_opener(
                urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(self.cookieJar),
                urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
                urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0))

            self.opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36")]


            forms = {"username": self.username,
                    "password": self.password
                    }

            data = urllib.urlencode(forms)
            req = urllib2.Request('http://www.example.com/login.phtml',data)
            res = self.opener.open(req)
            self.login_html =  res.read()

            if 'Welcome to Neopets!' in self.login_html:
                print 'Login Sucsessful!'

                break
            else:
                print 'Failed Login'
```

that works for both accounts here is my Buy Shares method:

```
def Buy_Shares(self):
        self.opener.addheaders = [('Referer','http://example.com/stockmarket.phtml?type=buy')]
        site = self.opener.open('http://www.example.com/stockmarket.phtml?type=list&full=true')

        html = site.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        text_list = []
        stocks_list = []
        for i in soup.findAll('b'):
            text_list.append(i.get_text())

        start = text_list.index('Change')+1
        stop = text_list.index('Search :')

        for i in range(start,stop):
            stocks_list.append(text_list[i])

        stocks = [stocks_list[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(stocks_list), 4)]
        for i in stocks:
            if i[2] == '17':
                stock_name = (i[0]).encode('utf-8')
                print stock_name
                break
            else:
                stock_name = None

        if stock_name != None:

            print "Buying"
            forms1 = {"ticker_symbol" : stock_name,
                     "amount_shares": "1000",
                     "type" : "buy",
                     "_ref_ck" : "587d56547765f577cfdaaa3a7ac8328c"
                    }
            data1 = urllib.urlencode(forms1)
            req1 = urllib2.Request('http://www.example.com/process_stockmarket.phtml?',data1)
            res1 = self.opener.open(req1)
            html = res1.read()
            print html

            if 'Portfolio' in html:
                print 'Sucsess'


        elif stock_name == None:
            print "No stock to buy"

        self.Sell_Shares()
```

like i said the program works with my account then when i try my friends account i get an error in the HTML output

i cant figure out why it works for one and not the other im thinking maybe because my browser has my account remembered but im not sure

someone please help been working on this for hours!

Thank You!

**UPDATE**

So i cleared all the saved  passwords from my browser and now neither of them work so i think it was the fact that i had my password saved so why isnt it working when i dont have the password saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the cookies don't match or `"_ref_ck" : "587d56547765f577cfdaaa3a7ac8328c"` is a user specific value.

Comment: yup im thinkin its the `_ref_ck` im gonna have to parse it from the page i feel dumb thanks!!